# Require same default xml namespace for parent and child element on serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I would like the parent and child element to have the same default namespace. I require this way because the serialized xml at the other end appears like that where the digital signature is being verified.

```
[XmlType("Parent", Namespace = "some-default-namespace")]
public class Parent
{
    [XmlElement("ChildOne", Namespace = "some-default-namespace", Order = 0)]
    public Child1 child1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ChildTwo", Namespace = "some-default-namespace", Order = 1)]
    public Child2 child2 { get; set; }
}
```

On XML Serialize I get this ...

```xml
<Parent xmlns="some-default-namespace">
   <ChildOne>
     ...
   </ChildOne>
   <ChildTwo>
     ...
   </ChildTwo>
</Parent>
```

Now, if I sign this XML and send the signed xml as the SOAP payload, this SOAP request payload gets deserialized into JAVA object and in the actual webservice method as part of the process, they serialize the JAVA object into xml to verify the digital signature. Their serialized xml looks as below, for whatever reason. That is why I would like to sign the xml that I have control over in the form as below

```xml
<Parent xmlns="some-default-namespace">
   <ChildOne xmlns="some-default-namespace">
     ...
   </ChildOne>
   <ChildTwo xmlns="some-default-namespace">
     ...
   </ChildTwo>
</Parent>
```

how can I get the desired output? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify *why* you need that output? It's an odd requirement given that the two are logically equivalent - in both cases, the child elements are in the required namespace. I would personally try to fix the requirement to handle the entirely-reasonable-output rather than trying to force serialization to give unusual output.

Comment: The XML serializer is an ancient, fickle beast that, in my opinion, sucks. Consider serializing "manually" using `XElement`, which has a very natural interface that makes writing the exact XML you want easy.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have to sign the xml I send as a SOAP request which gets deserialized and then serialized again in JAVA (which I don't have control over) for them to verify the signature. I am just trying to match and sign the xml as they get it, otherwise signature validation will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "as they get it"? (I'd suggest putting all of this detail into the question, along with where you're able to make changes. For example, would you be able to take the serialized output and modify it, or does this have to be done within the serialization step itself?)

Comment: You are right @JonSkeet, I have control over the serialized xml until I sign and send it. I thought it could be easily achieved as part of serialization itself. I have edited the post.

Comment: I think you need to add the setting to default (not remove duplicates).  Try             XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
            setting.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.Default;